# SQL check if column contains specific values

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
id     |  Values
------------------
  1    |  a
  1    |  b  
  1    |  c
  1    |  d
  1    |  e
  2    |  a
  2    |  a
  2    |  c
  2    |  c
  2    |  e
  3    |  a
  3    |  c
  3    |  b
  3    |  d
```

Now I want to know which id **contains** at least one of **a**, one of **b** and one of **c**.

This is the result I want:

```
   id
--------
  1
  3
```

Comment: it is a good practice to tag the dbms being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is aggregation with `having`:

```
select id
from t
where values in ('a', 'b', 'c')
group by id
having count(distinct values) = 3;
```

If you wanted more flexibility with the counts of each value:

```
having sum(case when values = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and
       sum(case when values = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and
       sum(case when values = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

or using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 'a' THEN 1 END) >= 1
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 'b' THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 'c' THEN 1 END) = 1;
```